# How are memory busses and capacity determined?

Tags: memory-hardware

If m = Ram quantity in GB, b =  bus width in bits, and n = a nonnegative integer, it appears that b = m•2^n and or m = w/2^n, what do the variables represent physically? I.e., what physically changes to, say, a GPU design if you change b, m, or n? E.g., how is the design different for m₁ = 5  and n₁=7 instead of m₂=10 and n₂=6?, I.e. for a 320-bit bus, what changes with 5GB instead of 10GB? Alternatively, what changes if w₁=192, n₁ = 6 vs w₂=384 and n₂=6 (obviously m would double, but why and what does that represent, or why can m be equal to any integer instead of being a power of 2))

Real world examples
128-bit bus (DDR modules, non-ECC) = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, …, 128 GB.
256-bit bus (like on 3070 or 4080) = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, …, 256 GB
320-bit bus (like 3080 10GB) = 5, 10, 20, 40, …, 320 GB
352-bit bus (like 1080 ti 11GB) = 11, 22, 44 GB
384-bit bus (like 3080 12GB or 3090 or 4090) = 6, 12, 24, or 48 GB

I feel almost as if the bit width is just m lanes of words 2^n bits long and n = module size but that wouldn’t explain why it’s always 2^n or is the 2^n just convenience because 2^n bytes is always 2^(n+3)bits and thus 2^n is simply a matter of convenience?

Comment: RAM chips come with a certain number of address bits (any number) and data bits (usually a power of 2). GPUs can be designed with various numbers of RAM busses and I think those are fixed depending on the GPU type. A lot of them support doubling the amount of RAM by having 2 chips per bus instead of just 1,

Comment: another interesting fact is the 352-bit and 320-bit cards are just 384-bit cards with one or two busses disabled. This could be done if some chips just have broken busses so they make cheaper cards out of those chips instead of throwing them away